# $\Bbb Z_n$ is a Field for all n

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have that $\Bbb Z_n$ ,  the integers mod n, is a **field** since $\forall  m $ $ \exists\mkern1.5mu l\,$ s.t.  $\,ml = 1 \Bbb Z_n$

That is to say that each number has a multiplicative inverse. I can see this for if n is a prime, but if you take $\Bbb Z_8$, then 2 does not have a multiplicative inverse since in mod 8:

$2 = \{0,2,4,6,8 \} $

How is $\Bbb Z_8$ a field then?

Comment: $Z_8$ is not a field. $Z_n$ is only a field when $n$ is prime, as you stated.

Comment: What what probably meant was that $\mathbb Z_n$ is a $\textbf{ring}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @DonThousand: Do you think that a Field is only a ring, as opposed to a field?

Comment: "I have that..." - whence?

Comment: No, I field is a ring with multiplicative inverses. $Z_n$ is a ring then for all n, but not a field unless n is irreducible?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, that seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @epsilonolispe Yes, it is only a field when $n$ is a prime (aka irreducible since $\mathbb Z$ is a UFD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false.  The correct statement would be that $\Bbb Z_n$ is a field iff $n$ is prime.  That guarantees multiplicative inverses for all nonzero elements.  For one thing, if $n$ is not prime, then $\Bbb Z_n$ is not even an integral domain.